# How do I Access separate pages of DataTable rows

Tags: c#, datatable, rowfilter

I have a *DataTable* with a large resultset.
This *DataTable* is used to generate multiple pages in a PDF (one for each row in the DataTable).
After a certain number of rows, the PDF generation takes too long, so I want to provide a list of hyperlinks for the end user to generate separate PDFs for each set of rows,
 i.e. Set 1 (Rows 0-90), Set 2 (Rows 91-181), etc.

I want to be able to filter the original DataTable whenever I generate a PDF for that set of rows. I know that GridViews offer Paging capability, but I don't want to plop the data into a gridview unnecessarily.

What I am hoping for is some kind of RowFilter where I can say:

```
_dt.RowFilter = "Rows(0-90)"
```

Does anyone know of such a feature of DataTables (using .NET 3.5)?

Or can anyone offer another solution? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - use the [AsEnumerable extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), then use LINQ to query the rows you need.

```
dataTable.AsEnumerable().Take(90);
```

Page 2:

```
dataTable.AsEnumerable().Skip(90).Take(90);
```

Comment: Ooh, that's cool, Does this make a copy of the original DataTable or does it just filter the source DataTable? (I want the latter).

Comment: Just filters - the IEnumerable<T> returned contains pointers to the actual data. From MSDN: "The enumerable object returned by the AsEnumerable method is permanently bound to the DataTable that produced it. Multiple calls to the AsEnumerable method will return multiple, independent queryable objects that are all bound to the source DataTable."